# GridView with ViewHolder crashes while scrolling

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridView which worked perfectly fine before until I used library AstickyHeader.  After the implementation of AstickyHeader Library  my app crashes while scrolling the grid view.

It seems like there is the problem in my ViewHolder that its getting null object reference. But it was working well before. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is getView() method of my GridViewAdapter.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
       // holder = null;

        Log.e("position",position+"");
        Product productItem = (Product) productList.get(position);

        if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.products_grid_item_layout, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.productImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
                holder.productImageClone = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.productImageClone);
                holder.detailsIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.detailsIcon);
                holder.productTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.productTitle);
                holder.productSubTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.productSubTitle);
                holder.productQuantity = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.productQuantity);
                holder.priceDollar = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.priceDollar);
                holder.priceCent = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.priceCent);
                holder.productCount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.productCount);
                holder.productGridLayout = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.productGridLayout);

                row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            Log.e("position tag",position+"");
        }

        String price = productItem.getPrice().toString();

        String[] pricearray;
        pricearray =  price.split("\\.");

        holder.productTitle.setText(productItem.getTitle().toString());
        holder.productSubTitle.setText(productItem.getSubtitle().toString());
        holder.productQuantity.setText(productItem.getVolume().toString());
        holder.priceDollar.setText(pricearray[0]+".");
        holder.priceCent.setText(pricearray[1]);


        if(productItem.getInCart()) {
            holder.productCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.productCount.setText(productItem.getVolume());
        }

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(productItem.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.favourites)
                .error(R.drawable.favourites)
                .into(holder.productImage);

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(productItem.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.favourites)
                .error(R.drawable.favourites)
                .into(holder.productImageClone);

        urlSlug = productItem.getUrlSlug();


        holder.detailsIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final int position = currentGridView.getPositionForView(v);
                Log.e("grid position", position+"");

                Intent productDetailIntent = new Intent(context,ProductDetailActivity.class);
                productDetailIntent.putExtra("url_slug", productList.get(position).getUrlSlug());

                context.startActivity(productDetailIntent);
            }

        });

        return row;
    }
```

Here is product_grid_item_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/productGridLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:background="@drawable/categories_grid_color_selector"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/demeterImage"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/productImageClone"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fav"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/productImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fav"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/productImage"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_16"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productDiscount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10% KORTING"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/productImage"
        android:background="@color/pink"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/productCount"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/productDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/productImage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_16">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text = "Product title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productSubTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/productTitle"
        android:text = "Product Sub title"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productQuantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/productSubTitle"
        android:text = "200 kg"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detailsIcon"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/info_circle"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_16"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/priceLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cart_price_height"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/priceDollar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0."
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            fontPath="fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/priceCent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="00"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            fontPath="fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/priceLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cart_price_height"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/priceLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/priceDollar2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0."
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            fontPath="fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/priceCent2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="00"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            fontPath="fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is error Log.

```
10-05 18:03:50.688 28933-28933/nl.proshore.ekoplaza E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: nl.proshore.ekoplaza, PID: 28933
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView nl.proshore.ekoplaza.adapter.ProductsGridViewAdapter$ViewHolder.productTitle' on a null object reference
                                                                          at nl.proshore.ekoplaza.adapter.ProductsGridViewAdapter.getView(ProductsGridViewAdapter.java:102)
                                                                          at nl.proshore.ekoplaza.utils.SimpleSectionedGridAdapter.getView(SimpleSectionedGridAdapter.java:329)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2360)
                                                                          at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1440)
                                                                          at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:366)
                                                                          at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:307)
                                                                          at android.widget.GridView.fillGap(GridView.java:267)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5191)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3573)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3982)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3807)
                                                                          at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9939)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2663)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2344)
                                                                          at dev.dworks.libs.astickyheader.ui.PinnedSectionGridView.dispatchTouchEvent(PinnedSectionGridView.java:487)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:411)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1810)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3061)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:373)
                                                                          at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10159)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4302)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3995)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3876)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4052)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3876)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6210)
```

Comment: Can you please show me the "getCount()" method of your adapter?

Comment: Please add products_grid_item_layout.xml

Comment: @AgustinSivoplás i have added the xml

Comment: @Aenadon I have used ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your view is null. Make sure that your textview is in  products_grid_item_layout.xml layout file or your viewHolder is null. I will debug code and find an issue.

And also one more tip do not use Gridview use Recyclerview. For example, refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/)